# Is compressed sensing for digital signals or could also be applied for discrete time signals?

Tags: compression, sparsity

I was wondering if is compressed sensing for digital signals? or could also be applied for discrete time signals?
What I mean is lets say I have a sampled but not quantized signals, can I find the sparse representation of it? 
Is there nice book or sth about that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please define what you mean by compressed sensing.  How are sampled signals different from quantized ones?  If I sample it at certain time steps and represent the sample with a number that has a given number of bits, isn't it quantized?